# How to Extract Id of inserted record which is return in response header message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers

**HttpResponseMessage** return here from webApi POST Verb message contain the the record id which is inserted how to extract that id in code behind

```
public HttpResponseMessage POST([FromBody]Map newmap)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SHATDbEntities entities = new SHATDbEntities())
                    {
                        entities.Maps.Add(newmap);
                        entities.SaveChanges();
                        var message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, newmap);
                        message.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + newmap.Id.ToString());
                        return message;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
                }
            }
```

**Here response ** Message received

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2351/");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
 new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(RequestURI, newmap).Result;
```

**At this point i want to extract that id from response message**
Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the needful.

```
var resultTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MyObject>("http://localhost/api/service",new MyObject()).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t => {
var response = t.Result;
var objectTask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyObject>().ContinueWith<Url>(u => {
    var myobject = u.Result;
    //do stuff 
});
});
```